# posting a form field with react-dropzone

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I need to upload a file with some related fields, like reference date and so on that are part of the form where the react-dropzone component is . How can I add the data of the form when the file is posted to the server?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I'm using fetch api

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${accessToken}`);

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("files", files[0]);
//ADD YOUR FIELDS HERE eg.
formdata.append("description", "Profile");
formdata.append("imageId", 13);

var requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata,
  redirect: "follow",
};

fetch(apiUrl, requestOptions).then((response) => response.json()).then((result) => console.log({ result }))
```